# Superheroes position about drugs

Tags: society, super-powers, law, behaviour

We often see superheroes confronting drug dealers and their henchmen, after all, drug use and commercialization in most countries is considered illegal. However, there is a growing current of thought that the best approach to drugs is to treat it as a public health problem rather than public safety because of its cost and impact on the safety of society.

Superheroes are often described as progressive as they tend to believe in human rights, peace, and social responsibility. Based on this premise, would not a superhero take a more political stance than fighting drugs? Wouldn't they rather pressure the government for drug liberalization rather than fight drug dealers in the streets as they usually do in different media?

Comment: That's half the Marvel Civil War story line, are you fighting for the greater good or are you a government stooge.

Comment: I was gonna write an answer on this, but its a bit offtopic TBH. TL;DW: super-outreach programs, super-charity work and super-advocacy just isn't as appealing to consumers of superhero fiction as punching petty criminals is. I have no idea why. The end result of this train of thought looks a bit like this: https://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=2305

Comment: Superheroes don't seem to have taken a political stance about abuse of legal, prescription drugs either.

Comment: This is a strange question. Why would it be surprising that American propaganda propagates the official position of the United States of America? It would be quite unexpected if such works promoted views contrary to the official orthodoxy.

Comment: *"Superheroes are often described as progressive as they tend to believe in human rights"* Oh yeah - the Punisher, George R.R. Martin's Sleeper and Black Shadow, Neil Gaiman's Sandman, Deadpool, Damien Wayne, Rorschach, Spawn, the Eradicator, the Crow et. al are all about human right things like fair trial and will never torture anyone. And don't get me started on their position about drugs.

Comment: @Renan that why I said "often". Sure there is a lot of superheroes that doesn't match such description.

Comment: “TL;DW: super-outreach programs, super-charity work and super-advocacy just isn't as appealing to consumers of superhero fiction as punching petty criminals is.” I dunno. Superman goes around helping with things like house fires and natural disasters.

Comment: drug USE is treated like a public health issue, drug dealing is still solidly in the criminal system, how often are superheroes shown attacking drug users.

Answer (score 5):

Superheroes are not perfect.  If they were their stories would be rather uninteresting.  This issue is one where different superheroes would likely have different opinions and take different stances.  Perhaps the conflict of opinions can lead to a very interesting story.  In fact, in [Batman: The Dark Knight Returns (part two)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_The_Dark_Knight_Returns_(film)), it's the political differences between Superman and Batman that lead to the "final showdown" - they're friends who don't want to fight each other, even actively avoiding the fight for some of the film, but their opinion on the role of government and their personal morality creates a situation where they *have* to fight.  This makes the Batman v Superman fight so thrilling and engaging (unlike that *other* movie).

So are you being manipulated by the government to do evil?  Is attacking crime, even if it comes from a broken place still good?  Are you a puppet? These are questions superheroes must wrestle with - *and that's the foundation for a great story!*

Some opinions superheroes might have on this issue include:

- **Public perception** - although we might *feel bad* for those drug addicted, "cleaning up the streets" often improves economies, makes people feel safer in their homes, etc.  Even though people *in theory* want those with drug issues to "get help", they don't want "those people" to be seen or heard.  The attitude in many cases is "go away from me *and get help*".  So a superhero might see themselves as giving them an ultimatum: stop causing problems for society and get help, or I'll be there to enforce the law.  This helps *public confidence* in society to grow.
- **I don't make the laws, I just enforce them.**  Something like Superman's "it's their world" mentality.  Just because you have powers doesn't mean you can defy the government.  Railroad companies in the second industrial revolution proved that: having the ability to defy the government doesn't necessarily give you the right to do so.  Is it more wrong to do drugs or to defy the government?  To enforce a stupid law, or to break social trust in those making the laws?
- **I'll only go after dealers**  Sympathy is for the user, not the dealers and drug lords.  Some superheros would only go after targets "higher up" in the food chain, not the purchasers.
- **Defiance** - refuse to enforce such laws, either quietly or loudly (ie "don't talk about it" versus "talk about it to news cameras" - both have their pros and cons).
- **Get Political** - recruit other superheroes to their position, use their fame to raise money for treatment plans (like many celebrities do), or so on.

There are many more approaches, but it all depends on the *character* of your superhero, and the world they are in.

In short, *use this conflict in your story!*

Answer (score 3):

There are two answers here, an in-universe one and a real-world one.

In-universe, it's simply that one does not go into the superhero business unless one is a self-righteous prig - someone who thinks s/he is superior to others, and so has an inherent right to tell them how to live.  Not something limited to superheroes (though they perhaps have more justification than most): it's common to politicians, religious figures, self-help gurus, nosy neighbors, etc. etc.

In the real world, it's just commercial reality.  Superheroes got their start in comic books, which faced a LOT of social disapproval.  If they hadn't bought into the anti-drug message (and other societal "goods"), they'd have faced even more, and likely would have been driven out of business.

Answer (score 0):

Drug crimes are always surrounded by others. To make any illegal business one would come to terror and/or murders or god knows what else.

Superheroes fight for justice against evil, "illegality". Drugs here are just a casus belli, not the essence of a war itself.

So, no superheroes would leave politics for politics (but may combine this two activities as Daredevil do/did), and do what can't be done by non-supers and hon-heroes. Specialisation, you know.

Comment: Drug crimes mostly exist BECAUSE drugs are illegal.

Comment: I have to note that I am against drug legalisation. the point is that there always be illegal goods/activities and they always would be superprofitable due to this illegality. And we can't legalaise everything.